# Difference between SDK vs LIB?

Tags: java

What is the difference between an SDK vs Library and any examples of custom implementation in Java ?

BR
/norbix

Answer (score 0):

> **A "library"** A fine grain physical concept associated with structured file type, such as PE[1], Mach-o[2] In lay terms, these are
>   used to provide "pre-canned" behavior available for coders to import
>   and reuse, sometimes offering services from the host operating system
>   such as network access, window management, user management; or as more
>   specific groups of behavior associated with an application specific
>   task, like creating custom behavior for a mail application when
>   filtering inbox content. Either way, a library is the unit of physical
>   reuse associated with software development.
>
> **An "SDK"** Is a coarse grain set of distributor libraries (and configuration tools) used to facilitate the adaptation of an approach,
>   technology or language in its entirety. examples include; Java SDK -
>   the complete library and tools used for creating Java software, as
>   defined by the original distributor Sql server SDK, a complete series
>   of libraries for accessing, managing and manipulating data, creating
>   custom behavior for, and via the Sql sever product range. These tend
>   to offer points for the developer to extend, which will be "called" by
>   the underlying platform, rather than the developer themselves. In this
>   way, they resemble a "framework".
>
> **A "tool kit"** This term is less popular these days Promotional term for a specialized library or small set of libraries dealing with a
>   very narrow problem domain. One example would be a "widget" library
>   for custom visual components.

[Source](https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/what-is-the-difference-between-toolkit-library-and-sdk/#post-0e2f4001-58cc-4a85-b7ca-d5786ccbb18e)

Found this on google and this perfectly answers your question

Comment: You should cite your sources, since you did not write this.

Comment: okay from next time i will take care of this .